# How to create a hyperlink of image to image in same word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I wanted to create a hyperlink of a image to another image in same word document so that when user click on image, cursor is navigated to another image and data is displayed.

Comment: [How to Add Internal Links to your Word Document](http://johnstilwell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-add-internal-links-to-your-word.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly forget to add details of what they have already attempted. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have two images (let's call them as image1 and image2) and you want, for example, when image1 is clicked, image2 will be navigated to and shown, right?

To do so, you need to create a bookmark to image2 first, then to create hyperlink to image2.

1. To create bookmark, select image2 then insert bookmark and name it;
2. To create hyperlink, select image1 and insert a hyperlink, in the dialog of "Edit Hyperlink", choose "Place in this document" first, then to choose the bookmark for image2 created just now, then click "OK".